# Existe alguma técnica para reportar erros do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, log

É o seguinte: Eu utilizo o Framework Laravel e, nele, configuro a aplicação para que, quando aconteça algum erro de servidor, ele me envie um e-mail, escreva num arquivo de log e/ou me envie uma mensagem no Telegram.

Isso de certa forma me ajuda a antecipar um problema antes que um cliente reclame que o sistema está dando erro.

No caso, algumas vezes, por motivo de publicação errada ou cache antigo, ao atualizar uma aplicação, alguns erros podem aparecer no console do Javascript e, por conta disso, alguma funcionalidade de uma aplicação fica prejudicada.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma técnica, um meio, ou algum padrão de comunicação de erro que pudesse ser aplicado no caso do Javascript?

Por exemplo, se um cliente, ao acessar a página, tiver algum problema com o `jQuery` porque a internet dele está bloqueando o CDN (content delivery network) do mesmo, isso gera um erro no console.

Existe alguma técnica ou um padrão para reportar esses erros, ou salvá-los num log, como geralmente se faz em aplicações do lado do servidor ?

Answer (score 2):

Olha, eu não acho que seja uma boa ideia guardar todos os erros de JavaScript. Erros de JavaScript ocorrem por diversas razões, podem ocorrer até mesmo por latência na conexão.
Mas se você realmente quiser registrar todos os erros, eu sugiro você sobrescrever o método `console.error()` que geralmente é chamado quando um erro é lançado.

```
//Armazeno o método console.error em uma variável para não perde-lo
const consoleError = console.error;

//Sobrescrevo o método console.error
console.error = function(...er) {

    //Chamo uma função AJAX para registrar o erro
    $.post("error.php", {error: er[0].toString()});

    //Chamo o método console.error padrão que foi armazenado em consoleError
    consoleError(...er);
}
```